# Json with \" not validating

Tags: java, json

So I'm testing my json validator and have json in my propertis file like:

```
jsonSource = {"kind": "Listing\""}
```

I get it with spring `@Value("${jsonSource}")` run it through:

```
   try {

            gson.fromJson(jsonSource, Object.class);
            return true;

        } catch(com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException ex) { 
            return false;
        }
```

or

```
   try {
            new JsonParser().parse(jsonSource);
            return true;
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            return false;
        }
```

And it dosen't validate.

I tried `jsonSource.replaceAll("\\", "\\\\");` on that string but no use.
I get my escaped json from http://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA.json (self_text) part

I guess I'm missing something really basic here, like what's happening under the hood with strings or how one should use json.

Comment: Is it written *exactly like that* in your property file? Because properties files use backslash for escaping, so you'd need to double it.

Comment: Yes, it's with one slash, because the json, i get is with one slash. So as i understand it gets escaped when it's put t string.. guess that solves it :)

Comment: The properties reader is *unescaping* it while it loads the file. You should log `jsonSource` before you parse it - I'm sure you'll find it doesn't have a slash at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm interpreting this:

> So I'm testing my json validator and have json in my propertis file like:

```
jsonSource = {"kind": "Listing\""}
```

As meaning you have a straight Java properties file which you're loading in a normal way. In that case, your string will be as if you'd written Java source code of:

```
String value = "{\"kind\": \"Listing\"\"}";
```

in other words, the string itself will contain:

```
{"kind": "Listing""}
```

Backslash in a properties file is used as an escape character - you need to double it if you want it to be in your *actual string*:

```
jsonSource = {"kind": "Listing\\""}
```

Comment: is there a way to import them without escaping? EDIT: No easy way I guess while looking at the web.

Comment: @MihkelL.: Don't use a properties file? Basically this *is* the properties file format - if you don't want to escape it, you'll need to use another format.